# Change a Label's behavior to support toggling by click in WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, label, toggle

Is there any way that I change a Label's behavior to support toggling by click in WPF?

i.e. that's `Selector.IsSelected` property toggle between "True" and "False" by clicking?

Regards.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
<StackPanel>
    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=checkbox}" Content="Hello">
        <CheckBox.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="CheckBox">
                <ContentPresenter/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </CheckBox.Template>
    </CheckBox>
    <CheckBox x:Name="checkbox" Content="A normal checkbox"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Note that the above template does *not* alter the appearance of the label based on whether it's checked or not. That might be something you'll need - hard to say without more information.

Comment: That's right dear Kent; I need an idea to do this, and your code give me that (^_^); My problem resolved. Regards.

Answer (score 2):

You would better use Checkbox for such behaviour and style it to your liking.

Remember controls in WPF represent behaviours not looks.

Answer (score 1):

Just want to add the way more simple solution of [mikelt21](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42956897/444231) in the [duplicate post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15087124/wpf-click-on-label-change-checkbox-ischecked-property):

```
<CheckBox>
    <Label Content="Your text here"/>
</CheckBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing I can think of is:

```
<CheckBox Content="Text goes here"/>
```

It is built-in behavior and if you are happy with the placement of the text (at the right of the CheckBox at least in my locale) there's no reason to make it more complicated.