# WPF clickable textblock MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, wpf-controls

Could you please help me?

I have a checkbox and a text block.

`<checkbox ..... />
<textblock ..... />`

They are for the ability to remember the password.

How do I make it so that when I click on the text block, the checkbox changes its status.

I can not break the structure of the mvvm pattern.

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15087124/wpf-click-on-label-change-checkbox-ischecked-property

Comment: nope, sorry. I need to use textblock + checkbox!

Comment: @j.doe, if the answer below does not help, then please explain why not. Do not just say "_Unfortunately no_". Explain what precisely you want to achieve and how the answer below does _not_ help you. Help us to help you...

Comment: yep. bad question. but idea is good (as i understand of course).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way

```
<CheckBox>
   <TextBlock Text="Your text here"/>
</CheckBox>
```

**Update**
You should use MVVM.
Without mvvm frameworks it will be something like this.

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:ViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
...
    <StackPanel>
        <CheckBox Name="CheckBox" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Your text here">
            <TextBlock.InputBindings>
                <MouseBinding Command="{Binding IsCheckedCommand}" MouseAction="LeftClick" />
            </TextBlock.InputBindings>
        </TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
```

Code behind

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    readonly Action<object> _execute;
    readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute) : this(execute, null) { }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        _execute = execute ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(execute)); _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute?.Invoke(parameter) ?? true;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add => CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
        remove => CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
    }
    public void Execute(object parameter) { _execute(parameter); }
}

public class ViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; } 

    public RelayCommand IsCheckedCommand { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        IsCheckedCommand = new RelayCommand(m => IsCheckedCommandExecute());
    }

    private void IsCheckedCommandExecute()
    {
        IsChecked = !IsChecked;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsChecked));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx

If you don't want to create custom implementation of ICommand and INotifyPropertyChanged you can take mvvm framework, e.g. MvvmLight

Comment: Unfortunately no
maybe I can somehow attach the text block to the checkbox