# Setting RenderTransform in a nested style

Tags: wpf, xaml, .net-3.5, styling

I'm using .NET 3.5 on Windows 8, with the default Aero theme.

This was supposed to be an answer to [Scale Checkbox without scaling content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24949927/scale-checkbox-without-scaling-content) but it didn't work as easily as I expected. I'm trying to:

1. scale the box in a checkbox control
2. in a style, so I can apply the change to all CheckBoxes (or only some)
3. independently of its text, with no need to compensate.

I have a **UserControl** with this Resources:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <!-- ... -->
        
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="../Resources/CheckBoxStyle.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

**Resources/CheckBoxStyle.xaml** is this:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:primitives="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;assembly=PresentationFramework">
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
        <Style.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type BulletDecorator}">
                <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="2" ScaleY="2"/>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

The **`primitives` namespace** is in case whatever I settle on needs to know what BulletDecorator is.

I found **BulletDecorator** in the Aero theme for .Net 3.5 from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970773.aspx), behind the "Default WPF Themes" link, per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4158681/639739).

I'm seeing no difference in the size of my checkbox boxes. I don't think I grabbed the wrong element type from the theme, but what else could be happening?

**Edit 1:**

BulletDecorator contains the checkbox's content anyway, so I tried dropping requirement #3. Now I have a huge box and huge text, and want to shrink the text back down. Here is **CheckBoxStyle.xaml**:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:primitives="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;assembly=PresentationFramework">
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
        <Style.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                            <ContentPresenter>
                                <ContentPresenter.LayoutTransform>
                                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.5" ScaleY="0.5" />
                                </ContentPresenter.LayoutTransform>
                            </ContentPresenter>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Style.Resources>
        <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="2" ScaleY="2"/>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found a solution, although it's not perfect. A better answer would still be accepted.

I used [Snoop](https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/)to determine that the element I'm concerned with is already a ContentPresenter. It contains a TextBlock, but for some reason that can't be styled (and it's shown in parentheses in Snoop's hierarchy). Here's my resulting **CheckBoxStyle.xaml**:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:primitives="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;assembly=PresentationFramework">
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
        <Style.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentPresenter}">
                <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.5" ScaleY="0.5" />
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Style.Resources>
        <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="2" ScaleY="2"/>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```